# Flatten multiple nested arrays in object

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, data-structures, recursive-datastructures

Please mark as duplicate if already solved.

The current structure : Array of Objects

```
const arrObj = [
  {
    head: 0,
    child_0: [
      { field: 0 },
      { field: 1 }
    ],
    child_1: [
      { field: 3 },
      { field: 4 },
      { field: 5 },
      { field: 6 }
    ],
    child_2: [
      { field: 7 },
      { field: 8 }
    ]
  }
]
```

Expected Output:

```
const newArrObj = [
  { head: 0, child_0: { field: 0 }, child_1: { field: 3 }, child_2: { field: 7 } },
  { head: 0, child_0: { field: 0 }, child_1: { field: 3 }, child_2: { field: 8 } },
  { head: 0, child_0: { field: 0 }, child_1: { field: 4 }, child_2: { field: 7 } },
  { head: 0, child_0: { field: 0 }, child_1: { field: 4 }, child_2: { field: 8 } },
  { head: 0, child_0: { field: 0 }, child_1: { field: 5 }, child_2: { field: 7 } },
  { head: 0, child_0: { field: 0 }, child_1: { field: 5 }, child_2: { field: 8 } },
  { head: 0, child_0: { field: 0 }, child_1: { field: 6 }, child_2: { field: 7 } },
  { head: 0, child_0: { field: 0 }, child_1: { field: 6 }, child_2: { field: 8 } },
  { head: 0, child_0: { field: 1 }, child_1: { field: 3 }, child_2: { field: 7 } },
  { head: 0, child_0: { field: 1 }, child_1: { field: 3 }, child_2: { field: 8 } },
  { head: 0, child_0: { field: 1 }, child_1: { field: 4 }, child_2: { field: 7 } },
  { head: 0, child_0: { field: 1 }, child_1: { field: 4 }, child_2: { field: 8 } },
  { head: 0, child_0: { field: 1 }, child_1: { field: 5 }, child_2: { field: 7 } },
  { head: 0, child_0: { field: 1 }, child_1: { field: 5 }, child_2: { field: 8 } },
  { head: 0, child_0: { field: 1 }, child_1: { field: 6 }, child_2: { field: 7 } },
  { head: 0, child_0: { field: 1 }, child_1: { field: 6 }, child_2: { field: 8 } },
]
```

Note that the array fields could be more than 2, as it is dynamic and have different lengths and property names. Been trying to figure this out for a day now.

Thanks

Comment: How many childs (`child0` and `child1`) could be there?

Comment: @gurvinder372 it is dynamic so i can't tell, it could be many as possible.

Comment: In case of dynamic number of childs, how should the output looks like?

Comment: @gurvinder372 like the one on the output, as long as it sees an array field

Comment: `...so on` - you've included sample input, please include **exact** required output ... and what you've tried

Comment: can you also post an example with child_0, child_1 and child_2 - just so the "algorithm" you want is clearer

Comment: You can't rely on head, child_0 or child_1 being accessed in any particular order. How will you deal with that?

Comment: @JaromandaX ive updated the output.

Comment: @RobG well there is an order, what ever the first accessed type of array field in the object and continue until there is no array left in the object.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `reduce` and a nested `for` loops.

I used spread here `{...child_0[k1]}` to clone the object and not just point by reference. If you just want to assign (point by reference), you can just use `child_0[k1]`

```js
const arrObj = [{head: 0,child_0: [{ field: 0 },{ field: 1 }],child_1: [{ field: 3 },{ field: 4 },{ field: 5 }]}];
 
const newArrObj = arrObj.reduce((c,{ head, child_0, child_1 })=>{
   for ( var k1 in child_0 ) {
          for ( var k2 in child_1 ) {
               c.push({
                  head : head,
                  child_0 : {...child_0[k1]},
                  child_1 : {...child_1[k2]},
               });
          }
   }
   return c;
},[]);
  
console.log( newArrObj );
```

---

For Multiple `child_*`, I borrowed the [permute()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21952437/combinations-of-elements-of-multiple-arrays) function on this post.

```js
const arrObj = [{head: 0,child_0: [{ field: 0 },{ field: 1 }],child_1: [{ field: 3 },{ field: 4 },{ field: 5 }],child_2: [{ field: 55 },{ field: 66 }]}];
const newArrObj = arrObj.reduce((c, {head,...child}) => {
  var keys = Object.keys(child);

  function permute(input) {
    var out = [];

    (function permute_r(input, current) {
      if (input.length === 0) {
        out.push(current);
        return;
      }

      var next = input.slice(1);

      for (var i = 0, n = input[0].length; i != n; ++i) {
        permute_r(next, current.concat([input[0][i]]));
      }
    }(input, []));

    return out;
  }

  permute(Object.values(child)).forEach((v, i) => {
    let t = {head: head};
    v.forEach((x, k) => {t[keys[k]] = {...x};});
    c.push(t);
  });

  return c;
}, []);

console.log(newArrObj);
```

Comment: And for *child_2*, *child_3*, …?